# Want to create a variable of datatype "Struct", and control (Array Size) of its sub element from outside

Tags: c++, arrays, size, external

I want to feed SIZE externally while declaring a variable of datatype "Struct" . Basically I want to use this datatype with different size.

```
struct ArrStruct final
{
    std::array<float32_t, SIZE> Arr1;
    std::array<float32_t, SIZE> Arr2;
};

struct Type1 final
{
    ArrStruct          var4;
    float32_t          var5;
};

struct StructData final
{
    Type1           var1;
    float32_t       var2;
    float32_t       var3;
};


struct Struct final
{
    StructData         Data;
};
```

Comment: What should `SIZE` be? You know that it must be fixed at compile-time, right?

Comment: Note: In embedded cant use "std::vector"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `SIZE` a template argument:

```
template <size_t SIZE>
struct ArrStruct final
{
    std::array<float32_t, SIZE> Arr1;
    std::array<float32_t, SIZE> Arr2;
};

template <size_t SIZE>
struct Type1 final
{
    ArrStruct<SIZE>    var4;
    float32_t          var5;
};

template <size_t SIZE>
struct StructData final
{
    Type1<SIZE>     var1;
    float32_t       var2;
    float32_t       var3;
};

template <size_t SIZE>
struct Struct final
{
    StructData<SIZE>     Data;
};
```

`Struct<42>` is then a `Struct` with a `StructData<42>` which in turn has a member of type `Type1<42>` and that has a member of type `ArrStruct<42>` which contains arrays of size `42`.

Comment: Thanks for the trick : 463035818_is_not_a_number .
Its really helpful ,a nd solved my blocker.

Comment: @SanjivSingh its not a "trick". Templates are a fundamental feature of C++. You are already using templates when you use `std::array`. I can only suggest to read more elsewhere about it, because even if I would add more to the answer I could only scratch the surface

Comment: Recently I switched to c++ . I am exploring .
Anything you will write .... will be helpful .

Answer (score 0):

you can use a c++ macro in this case called SIZE. Also I failed to find a float32_t data type so I just went with float which has a size of 32 bits.

```
#define SIZE 3

struct ArrStruct final
{
    std::array<float, SIZE> Arr1;
    std::array<float, SIZE> Arr2;
};
```